# AppEngine authentication through Node.js

Tags: google-app-engine, google-authentication

I'm trying to write a VSCode extension where users could log into Google AppEngine with a google account, and I need to get their `SACSID` cookie to make appengine requests.

So I'm opening a browser window at

> https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp://localhost:3000/

(generated by `google.appengine.api.users.create_login_url`)

The user logs in and is redirected to my local webserver at

> localhost:3000/_ah/conflogin/?state={state}

Now I try to forward the request to my AppEngine app (since it knows how to decode the state parameter), so I do a request to

> https://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/conflogin/?state={state}

basically just replacing localhost with the actual app.

but it doesn't work, presumably because the domain is different. I assume this is on purpose, for security.

Is there any way I can make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but the only solution I've found is to have an endpoint on my GAE instance that does the redirection. Then I can set that as the continue url, when I'm starting the authentication process

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3D**https://my-app.appspot.com/redirect?to=http://localhost:3000**

Answer (score -1):

I think you should center the attention on the protocols you are using, since it’s known that the cookie name is based on the http protocol (HTTP : ACSID, HTTPS:SACSID), and that’s the security perspective till this point for me.

Having the error you are facing now would be helpful to understand the problem better. Also, how are you performing the call to the API and the code you are using would be helpful too.